# Writing a wrapper program in Java for adb

Tags: java, adb

I need to write a java application that detects a USB device, and can be used to pass commands, similar to adb (Android Debug Bridge).

Since, java does not provide usb support. I intend to use some kind of java wrapper program for utilizing adb functions. Am I thinking rightly ? If yes, how do I proceed ? How do I create wrapper programs in Java? Could someone point me to some useful resources.

Thank you.
Carl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not familiar with *adb*, but a general way to utilize USB and other system resources is [JNI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/). That way u can write a really simple utility class, that just holds some native methods which are implemented in a system library.

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write a wrapper program that will call the `adb` command line tool. You can also use this pure java library.

https://github.com/vidstige/jadb

Note: I'm the author of this library, just to state my affiliations.